# Imprimir total de query count en un label

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

Que tal, estoy tratando de imprimir el total de un `query count` en un `label`, pero al momento de llamar el resultado solo imprime un `System.Data.DataRow`

Este es mi `query`

```
/***********GET ALL THE FAKE TOOLS FROM FCH*************/
public class area_success_FCH
{
    public DataTable Sfchconnect()
    {
        string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

        DataTable SfchTable = new DataTable();

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
            bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
            String qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM area WHERE standby = 1 AND area = 'FCH'";

            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = qry;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            command.Connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); // close conn after 
            SfchTable.Load(reader);
            if (!reader.IsClosed)
            {
                reader.Close();
            }

            return SfchTable;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return SfchTable;
    }
}
/*******************************************************/
```

el query esta en una carpeta llamada `conexiones` y esta tiene una clase donde tiene el query

despues el `DataTable` lo mando a llamar desde el `dashboard.aspx` que es una pagina comun en el archive raiz

```
/********************************FILL COUNT CLOUD******************************/
    conexiones.area_success_FCH Sfchconnect = new conexiones.area_success_FCH();
    conexiones.area_success_FCH SfchTable = new conexiones.area_success_FCH();
    /******************************************************************************/

if (!IsPostBack)
        {

            Lbl_notu.Text = notu.Rows[0].ToString();
```

resultado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Lbl_notu.Text = notu.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

Para que puedas accesar al elemento de [Reglón][Columna], espero te ayude, tengo un función para devolver solo 1 elemento de consultas por si ocuparas. Saludos

Comment: Perfecto!! mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Si vas a usar funciones de agregación (que devuelven un solo valor), no deberías devolver un `DataTable`, sino un valor, en este caso al ser un `COUNT`, un entero.

Entonces ,  declara un `int count` y devuelve ahí el resultado de `ExecuteScalar`, que devuelve la primera fila de la primera columna del resultado de tu consulta (El `COUNT`)

```
try
{
    connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
    bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
    String qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM area WHERE standby = 1 AND area = 'FCH'";

    command.Connection = connection;
    command.CommandText = qry;
    connection.Open();
    count = command.ExecuteScalar();
    connection.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
return count;
```

Comment: ooh ya entiendo! tomare en cuenta tu consejo muchas gracias

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos coincido con la respuesta de FederHico, aunque tampoco es recomendable tener un bloque `catch` que no haga nada, lo ideal, también sería realizar el manejo de ese error.